# Smoothness of a solution to an integral equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $v$ be a real function satisfying the integral equation $$v(x) = c\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{\lvert x-y\rvert^{\alpha}}{(v(y)+P(y))^q}\,dy$$ where $c>0$, $q>0$, and $\alpha>0$ are given constants and $P:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ is a given smooth function. How can I show that $v$ is smooth?